# Флажок на html/css

Tags: html, css

Можно ли как-нибудь воссоздать такой флажок на css/html?

[image: Флажок]

p.s. - интересует только флажок,без жёлтой полосы.

Comment: да, можно воссоздать на css/html

Answer (score 11):

Например так:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
.flag {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.flag::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

еще как вариант

```css
.flag {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 70%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 70%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Создаешь блок и добавляешь стили

```css
.flag {
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
}
.flag:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border-left: 20px solid #000;
  border-right: 20px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flag"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<svg style="width:150px;height:200px;">
<polygon 
points="10 190, 10 10 ,140 10,140 190,70 80 " 
style="fill: red; fill-opacity:1; stroke: red;" /> 
</svg>
```

Ну и я свои пять копеек вставлю

Answer (score 0):

Флажок можно разбить на 3 фигуры: 1 прямоуглольник и 2 треугильника.

Прямоугольник можно сделать простым дивом, с красным бэкгрундом.

[Сдесь](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/treugolniki-cherez-css) описано как на html+css создавать треугольники.